# error joining tables in php mysql

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to join tables in php mysql. Here's my code:

```
public public function getResponInfo($kode_laporan)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('laporan l, respon_user ru, respon r');
    $this->db->join('admin a', 'a.id_admin = r.id_admin', 'left');
    $this->db->join('respon_user ru', 'ru.kode_laporan = r.kode_laporan', 'left');
    $this->db->join('user u', 'u.id = ru.id_pengirim', 'left');
    $this->db->where("r.kode_laporan = '". $kode_laporan."'");
    //$this->db->order_by('r.tanggal', 'asc');
    return $this->db->get();
}
```

[And it got error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIB0R.png)

All I want to do is to display

'isi_respon' and 'tanggal' from **respon** table,
 'nama_opd' from **admin** table,
 'isi_respon' and 'tanggal' from **respon_user** table, 
'nama' from **user** table.

Then, I want to order them by "tanggal" from **respon and respon_user** tables.

Both tables respon and `respon_user` have `kode_laporan` from **laporan** table.

Is it possible to do that? thank you for your help

**updated**
I think all the codes that u've given to me are working. but i got another problem to display them through the controller and view files.
here's my controller code:

```
public function detailLaporan($kode_laporan)
{
    $data['page']='detaillaporan';
    $data['laporan'] = $this->Home_model->getLapDetail($kode_laporan);
    $data['id'] = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $data['respon'] = $this->Home_model->getResponInfo($kode_laporan)->result();
    $data['rsp'] = $this->Home_model->getResponInfo($kode_laporan)->num_rows();
    $data['kode_laporan'] = $this->session->set_userdata('kode_laporan');
    $this->load->view('home/master', $data);
}
```

view:

```
if($rsp > 0){
        foreach ($respon as $r) {
           echo $r['tanggal'];
           echo $r['nama']; 
           /*i want to display 'nama' or 'nama_opd', 
             it depends on whether it belongs to 'respon' or 'respon_user' table*/
           $r['isi_respon'];
           }
}
```

Comment: Use only one table in from clause and then use two more joins to add respon_user and respon.

Comment: @FahadAnjum i tried that but i got another error in the view files. perhaps i wrote the wrong code in controller or view file?? i have no idea

Answer (score 0):

**Please try the below code**

```
$this->db->select('r.isi_respon, r.tanggal as respon_tanggal, a.nama_opd, ru.isi_respon as respon_user_isi_respon, ru.tanggal as response_user_tanggal, u.nama');
$this->db->from('respon r');
$this->db->join('admin a', 'a.id_admin = r.id_admin', 'left');
$this->db->join('respon_user ru', 'ru.kode_laporan = r.kode_laporan', 'left');
$this->db->join('user u', 'u.id = ru.id_pengirim', 'left');
$this->db->where("r.kode_laporan = '". $kode_laporan."'");
$this->db->order_by('r.tanggal, ru.tanggal', 'asc');
return $this->db->get();
```

Comment: I think it works, but I have no idea the codes i have to write on the controller file and view file??

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('l.*,ru.*,r.*,a.*,u.*');
$this->db->from('laporan l');
$this->db->join('admin a', 'a.id_admin = r.id_admin', 'left');
$this->db->join('respon_user ru', 'ru.kode_laporan = r.kode_laporan', 'left');
$this->db->join('user u', 'u.id = ru.id_pengirim', 'left');
$this->db->where("r.kode_laporan = '". $kode_laporan."'");
$this->db->order_by('r.tanggal', 'asc');
return $this->db->get();
```